# Reading from wrapped GZipStream

Tags: c#, gzipstream

I am trying to read compressed gzip data like this:

```
using (var input = new BinaryReader(new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))) 
{
    while(input.PeekChar() != -1)
    {
        //use BinaryReader methods I need
    }
}
```

But `GZipStream` `CanSeek` property is always `false`, so `input.PeekChar()` is always `-1`.
I don't want to work with `GZipStream` directly. I can't read whole file, because it can be too big. I can't read by byte arrays, because I parse data afterwards so some bytes can't be split and must be parsed together.
 Is there a way to determine if eof occured using `BinaryReader` without catching exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to determine if eof occured using BinaryReader without catching exception?

Not a good one.  Technically you could wrap GZipStream in a custom stream that supports seeking using a small buffer.  But that's not worth the effort.

Catching an exception has an insignificant cost in a code path that does IO.

Comment: Then ditch BinaryReader and work with the GZipStream directly using BitConverter.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Nah, making seekable stream will be less painful in my case.